# Detect key input

Tags: move

I want to make a game in python with a player you can move but when I make these lines of code

```
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[K_d]:
    playerx += 5
```

It says that K_d is not defined in the console. What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the `K_d` to `pygame.K_d` like this:

```
keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_d]:
    playerx += 5
```